# Select data from the last complete row

Tags: mysql

I have a spreadsheet that is being migrated into a MySQL database. In the future the spreadsheet won't be filled in. Data will be uploaded directly to the database. The spreadsheet is now in two tables. One, called Piles, contains info on the product. The other, called Cubes, contains test results performed on the products. Sample data from the two tables is below:

Piles:

```
+----------+------------+---------+-----------------+
| ID       | Date       | MouldID | StockCode       |
+----------+------------+---------+-----------------+
| 23A42895 | 2017-06-09 | 23A     | 250CDJ09.0/0412 |
| 23B42895 | 2017-06-09 | 23B     | 250CDJ07.0/0412 |
| 642895   | 2017-06-09 | 6       | 250CDJ09.0/0412 |
| 8642895  | 2017-06-09 | 86      | 250CDJ07.0/0412 |
| 842895   | 2017-06-09 | 8       | 250CDJ09.0/0412 |
+----------+------------+---------+-----------------+
```

Cubes:

```
+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
| ID      | Date       | ConcTotalM3 | MouldID |
+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
| 2342895 | 2017-06-09 |        18.1 |      23 |
| 4842895 | 2017-06-09 |        57.9 |      48 |
|  842895 | 2017-06-09 |       108.4 |       8 |
| 1542895 | 2017-06-09 |       154.7 |      15 |
| 6242895 | 2017-06-09 |       204.6 |      62 |
+---------+------------+-------------+---------+
```

Now the spreadsheet was filled in by hand. When the Mould ID and Date matched the info was all written on one row. The data in the cubes table was then dragged down until another matching row was found and the process repeated.

My question is, how can i write a sql query that would output the same. I can ofc write a query that joins on date and MouldID but this won't "drag data down" Note if the numeric part of MouldID matches then that is a match for the row. A and B doesnt matter. I have included what I would expect the output to be from the sample data for reference.

```
+----------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| ID       | Date       | MouldID | StockCode       | ConcTotalM3 |
+----------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| 23A42895 | 2017-06-09 | 23A     | 250CDJ09.0/0412 |        18.1 |
| 23B42895 | 2017-06-09 | 23B     | 250CDJ07.0/0412 |        18.1 |
| 642895   | 2017-06-09 | 6       | 250CDJ09.0/0412 |        18.1 |
| 8642895  | 2017-06-09 | 86      | 250CDJ07.0/0412 |        18.1 |
| 842895   | 2017-06-09 | 8       | 250CDJ09.0/0412 |       108.4 |
+----------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Edit:
So i have removed some columns for clarity as i think it was confusing things. I don't have a using a join with the MouldID. At the moment i am using a script which tells me the position of the letter in the string. Then i use left() to get the number part only.

What i can't do is get the join to work to use the last match if it can't match the current row. To explain my example output the first two lines are matches as there is a mould 23 in the Cubes table. Mould 6 doesn't have a match so it uses the last match (from the row above). The same occurs for mould 86. Mould 8 does have a match in the Cubes table so it uses that.
I hope this clears things up a bit more. Thanks

SQL Fiddle for reference:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f19df/2

Comment: Restrict the data set to just the relevant columns, and see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: In ID you have only A or B or you can have also others char ??

Comment: @scaisEdge only A or B or S at the moment

Comment: @Strawberry Better? Enough info but not too much to over complicate it?

Comment: @cheesemarathon A vast improvement. But I'm confused. Does the accepted answer solve the problem, or not?

Comment: @Strawberry Solve it, no. But it has told me that it's not possible just with an SQL Query.

Comment: Well, what if they're mistaken? Now we'll never know ;-)

Comment: You know, the real problem here is your ids. They're a mess. You've confused the id that represents the machine's ability to relate one piece of data with another with the id that allows a human to find the sample on a shelf. They're two completely different things and need have no (humanly-discernible) relationship to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pair of nested  replace for avoid A , B  and match with cubes.ID

```
    select 
      Date
      , a.MouldID
      , a.StockCode
      , a.Length 
      , a.Serials
      , a.PrintNum
      , b.ConcTotalM3
      , b.Quantity
      , b.Time 
      ....
    from  Piles a
    inner join Cubes b on replace(replace(a.ID, 'A', '') , 'B','') = b.id
```

looking to your sqlfiddle  this match

```
  a.Date
  , a.ID
  , b.ID
  , replace(replace(a.ID, 'A', '') , 'B','')
  , a.MouldID
  , a.StockCode
  , b.ConcTotalM3
from  Piles a
inner join Cubes b on replace(replace(a.ID, 'A', '') , 'B','') = b.ID
```

Comment: Would be nice to just keep the numeric values and join since it appears other values may be provided over time.

Comment: I have asked  to the OP if The id contain only A or B  .. so for the moment  should work ..s  +

Comment: @scaisEdge Matching the MouldID is not what i am unable to do here. Please see my edit for more clarity on the problem

Comment: my query where work on id  not on MouldID ..  what do you mean ..?

Comment: @scaisEdge Sorry i see this now. See here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f19df/2 This does not match my example output. It only shows exact matches. I want it to show the last match found if it cant find a match, explained better in my edit

Comment: I don't understand   .. you have id with char and id without char  .. in my test using replace this work ..  .. i have update the asnwer  with my query test .. based  on your fiddle ..  otherwise  . .. i don't understand you question  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks for your help. I don't think i am explaining myself well. Take a look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba8c02/1. The 2 that return null. I want those to contain 18. From the row above where there was a match. So if there is no match. Return the last match

Comment: I think that this is not possibile using sql only  .. you can do this server side (or using a store  procedure) .. scanning the query result, preserving the last valid value and when you get null value assigne the preserved  one  .. ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks, ill look into a procedure to run on insert to add results when null returned